# How do I adjust the gamma on my HDMI monitor?

Tags: display, system-settings

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607444/the-white-on-my-screen-is-too-bright-how-should-i-adjust-the-gamma), and that works on my VGA monitor, but my main monitor is connected via HDMI, and xcalib and xgamma don't work on it. How do I reduce the gamma? This is really getting to be an issue because I can hardly use this OS because of how bright the white is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem and was about to post a question on it, but managed to find an answer.

First use:

```
xrandr
```

To find the name of the output. It could be (HDMI-0 or HDMI-1 etc.)

Then do:

```
xrandr --output <Channel> --brightness <Level>
```

Brightness is a decimal number from 0 to 1. For example, this is the command I did to fix my problem:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

`xrandr --output {Channel}  --gamma R:G:B`

for example:

`xrandr --output HDMI1 --gamma .5:.5:.5`

Answer (score 0):

I just installed QRedshift to solve the same problem. It lets you adjust brightness, color temp, and gamma for daytime vs nighttime use with your mouse. I bumped my gamma up from 1.0 to 1.1 and it's made a noticeable difference.